# Change the display of a list took from text file

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, int, text-files

I have this code wrote in Python:

```
with open ('textfile.txt') as f:
     list=[]
     for line in f:
          line = line.split()
          if line: 
              line = [int(i) for i in line] 
              list.append(line)
     print(list)
```

This actually read integers from a text file and put them in a list.But it actually result as :

```
[[10,20,34]]
```

However,I would like it to display like:

```
10 20 34
```

How to do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Don't print the list itself. You could iterate through the list and print each element, or your could use the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method for strings.

Comment: formatting! it'd go a long way to helping you :)

Comment: @thegrinner if I use print(' '.join(map(str,list))) it result as [10,20,34] theres still [ ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just want to add the items to the list, rather than appending them:

```
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    list = []
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        if line:
            list += [int(i) for i in line]

    print " ".join([str(i) for i in list])
```

If you append a list to a list, you create a sub list:

```
a = [1]
a.append([2,3])
print a    # [1, [2, 3]]
```

If you add it you get:

```
a = [1]
a += [2,3]
print a    # [1, 2, 3]!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    lines = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]

print(' '.join(lines))
```

With an input file 'textfiles.txt' that contains:

```
10
20
30
```

prints:

```
10 20 30
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to print a list of lists.  The easiest way to do that is to iterate over it and print each list.

```
for line in list:
    print " ".join(str(i) for i in line)
```

Also, I think `list` is a keyword in Python, so try to avoid naming your stuff that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the file is not extremely long, if you want the list of integers, you can do it at once (two lines where one is the `with open(...`. And if you want to print it your way, you can convert the element to strings and join the result via `' '.join(...` -- like this:

```
#!python3
# Load the content of the text file as one list of integers.
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    lst = [int(element) for element in f.read().split()]

# Print the formatted result.
print(' '.join(str(element) for element in lst))
```

Do not use the `list` identifier for your variables as it masks the name of the list type.